# SignatureDoesNotMatch on PUT request for AWS presigned url

Tags: jquery, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, put, pre-signed-url

There are a number of questions/answer related to this, but they do not seem to apply to my situation or the answer does not appear to solve this.

I have a AWS lambda function that returns a `getSignedUrl` generated by this function: `getUploadURL`

```
const getUploadURL = async function() {
  console.log('getUploadURL started')
  let actionId = Date.now()

  var s3Params = {
    Bucket: uploadBucket,
    Key:  `${actionId}.csv`,
    ContentType: 'text/csv',
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Get signed URL
    let uploadURL = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params)
    resolve({
      "statusCode": 200,
      "isBase64Encoded": false,
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },
      "body": JSON.stringify({
          "uploadURL": uploadURL,
          "csvFileName": `${actionId}.csv`
      })
    })
  })
}
```

My intention is that this generates a URL (i.e., `uploadURL`), to which I can post/put/send a csv file, and that this csv is then automatically saved at s3 bucket `uploadBucket`. I have an AWS API gateway pointing towards this function with a specific url endpoint. I can send a jquery GET request to this API endpoint, and it will return the `uploadURL`.

```
var req = $.ajax({ 
      method:"GET",
      url:url_endpoint, // the API Gateway endpoint that points towards the lambda running `getUploadURL`
    });
```

Here `req.response` text appears to be correct:

```
{"uploadURL":"https://materialcomv2.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/very_long_url","csvFileName":"1611509250475.csv"}
```

Then, I have some `text/csv` data, which I intend to send to the `uploadURL`

```
data = "111,222,333\naaa,bbb,ccc\nAAA,BBB,CCC".
```

At first I tried a simple request (below), but this return an `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error.

```
req= $.ajax({
      url: target_url, // this is the `uploadURL`
      method:"put", 
      data:data, // this is the csv data
    })
```

Based on what I understand, this is caused by the ajax put paramaters not matching the lambda `s3Params`. I tried to add `contentType:'text/csv',` and a `key:csvFileName`. I tried to send it as a `blob`, and as a formdata, but all to no success.

What do I need to change so I no longer get the `SignatureDoesNotMatch` and can succesfully upload a csv to a bucket?

Comment: Can you check your S3 permissions, for if the bucket is allowed to be updated from public?

Comment: @FaizaanKhan good question, but I believe it is. In the `CORS` settings, I have `AllowedOrigins:*` and `PUT` within the allowedmethods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in my case I wanted to send a csv. I decided it'd be easier to send a .txt file, and then read it as csv. This made me change my content-type to 'txt'.

Besides this, I needed to have my bucket configured to (also) contain:

```
 "AllowedHeaders": [
      "*"
  ],
  "AllowedMethods": [
      "GET",
      "PUT"
  ]
```

Next, in my ajax put request, it should read:

```
$.ajax({
      url: uploadURL, 
      type: "put",  // I originally had method:"put", which was failing. 
      data: data,   // Data here is just a string
      contentType: 'text',
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, setting the signature version when creating the S3 object fixed the problem.

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  signatureVersion: "v4",
});
```